# Error received saying "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm doing simple application to run SQL server database C# form application. In action of code "INSERT INTO", the following error occurred.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 12' to data type int.

Following is the code:

```
{
    String conString = @"DataSource=DESKTOP2V4K24T\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=Student_Enrollment_System_DB;Integrated Security=True";
    string query = "INSERT INTO Students(Registration_Number,Student_Name,Date_of_Birth,Gender,Contact_Number,Course_enrolled_in) " +
        "VALUES('" + RegNo + "','" + StuName + "','" + DateOfBirth + "','" + textBox1 + "','" + ContactNo + "','" + CsesEnrolledIn + "')";

    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand runquery = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    conn.Open();
    runquery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Student have been added!");
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says you cannot concat System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a string.

You should concat textBox1.Text instead of textBox1.

The second line would be:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Students(Registration_Number,Student_Name,Date_of_Birth,Gender,Contact_Number,Course_enrolled_in) " +
    "VALUES('" + RegNo + "','" + StuName + "','" + DateOfBirth + "','" +
            textBox1.Text + "','" + ContactNo + "','" + CsesEnrolledIn + "')";
```

Comment: You should explain this.

Comment: In the query variable you are concatenating the textBox1 control.

Change the second line to:

string query = "INSERT INTO Students(Registration_Number,Student_Name,Date_of_Birth,Gender,Contact_Number,Course_enrolled_in) " +
        "VALUES('" + RegNo + "','" + StuName + "','" + DateOfBirth + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + ContactNo + "','" + CsesEnrolledIn + "')";

Comment: [edit] that into your answer, not as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Preparing and using an inline query is not a good practice. Your code will not work when some one enters special character like single quote in text box . Instead , use parameterized query and pass the textbox values to the parameters.

Comment: Besides being a bad practice, it is also a sql injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting Text value of a TextBox into an INT field, this is normal behaviour. You can't stuff a string into an int.
You need to convert the value. Int32.Parse(TextBox.Text)